# Creating a line/bar chart using DateTimeIndex as x-axis (double axis = month/year)

Tags: python, date, matplotlib

My name is Sod, an amateur at data sciene. This is my first post and I apologize if it is not up to standard. I tried embedding image but found out you need reputation points to do so. As such, I could only provide links. I have edited the post follow Trenton's advice and hope it is reproducible now.

I have been trying to create this chart for the last 7-8 days and keep having multiple difficulties. I have looked through many stackoverflow posts but to no avail. As such, I created an account in hopes of assistance. Hopefully I can give back to the community in the near future.

```
# Import modules/packages
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.dates import MonthLocator, DateFormatter

# Create sample random dataframes with DateTimeIndex
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(56, 5))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(56, 3))

# Add a monthly frequency DateTimeIndex starting from 2017
df.index = pd.date_range('2017-01-01', periods=len(df), freq='MS')
df2.index = pd.date_range('2017-01-01', periods=len(df2), freq='MS')

# Use pyplot to configure chart settings including font, background , etc
plt.rcParams['font.serif'] = ['Times New Roman']
plt.rc('legend',**{'fontsize':4},frameon=False)
plt.style.use('ggplot')
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,8))

# Plot a bar and line chart together using DateTimeIndex as x-axis ticks/labels
df.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, y=df.columns[0], color='darkblue', ax=ax)
df.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, y=df.columns[1], color='blue', ax=ax)
df.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, y=df.columns[2], color='yellow', ax=ax)
df.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, y=df.columns[3], color='green', ax=ax)
df.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, y=df.columns[4], color='gray', ax=ax)
df2.plot(kind='line',y=df2.columns[0], use_index=False, ax=ax)

# Label minor ticks with month's non-zero padded digit (e.g. March = 3)
ax.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(DateFormatter('%#m'))


print(df.head(5))
               0     1     2     3     4
2017-01-01  1.10  0.48 -0.22 -1.14  0.59
2017-02-01  3.59 -1.26  0.49 -0.03  0.88
2017-03-01  1.96 -1.95  0.38  0.17  0.63
2017-04-01  1.26  0.62  1.90  1.20 -2.46
2017-05-01  0.88 -0.35 -0.80  0.93  0.26
```

**Current Output (using sample random data created above):**
[Link 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYQnH.png)

**Current Difficulties:**

1. Bar and Line are indexed differently showing different x-labels. Which plots x-axis labels and ticks be better for a DateTimeIndex? - link 1 and 2.
2. How to create a two x-axis's where the month shows on the top, and the year shows on the bottom as seen in the Desired Output image link. I also want it to show only quarterly month labels (i.e. 3,6,9,12) except to always include the very last month at the end (i.e. 8) as seen in link 3.
3. For some reason my bars are not stacking properly even though they have the same DateTimeIndex as seen in link 2.
4. Is it possible to have the average largest stacked bar on the very bottom, and the next largest stacked bar on the 2nd bottom, etc.?
5. Is it possible to include a data label for the very last data value from the line chart? As show in link 3.

**Current Output (using proprietary data):**
[Link 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPIdy.png)

**Desired Output (using proprietary data):**
[Link 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MSv7P.png)

Comment: No, because the xticks of a barplot are 0 indexed, where each bar is a separate xtick. The xaxis is not a datetime ranged index like with a line plot. The date shown on the axis is just the text label.

Comment: Thank you @TrentonMcKinney. I have formatted my text and tried to follow the steps in the links you provided. I hope this is much better.